# How to deal with milliseconds in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am working with a bot, and I need to sort the event by a datetime column, when I import the column from my database I have this format:

```
2017-10-19T14:26:57.2349278Z
```

after importing in power BI and changing the data type to date time I get this:

```
10/19/2017 02:26:57 PM
```

all the trailing milliseconds are truncated, but I need them to sort correctly the events, because some events occurs in the same second.

Any body any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: It's not supported as you can see the related Power BI idea [here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/15906970-milliseconds-as-format-option-for-date-time). The best you can do is to treat it as text and break it into two parts `2017-10-19T14:26:57`, `.2349278Z` for further comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with a sample table of dates in your format, when loaded into Power BI, this is the result.

[image: Loaded data]

Click on the Navigation step and then click on Add Column -> Custom Column. A prompt will pop up asking if you want to insert a step, click Insert.

[image: Insert step]

In the prompt, enter the following formula.

```
Text.Start([#"Timestamp"], 4) & 
Text.Middle([#"Timestamp"], 5, 2) & 
Text.Middle([#"Timestamp"], 8, 2) & 
Text.Middle([#"Timestamp"], 11, 2) & 
Text.Middle([#"Timestamp"], 14, 2) & 
Text.Middle([#"Timestamp"], 17, 2) & 
Text.Middle([#"Timestamp"], 20, 7)
```

[image: New column]

This gives you a column that can be used to sort the items in the table by a precise datetime. Note that the custom column formula requires the raw date string to be in the exact same format as in your question.

[image: Results]