# Duration wrongly converted to Date-Time type

Tags: powerbi

I am getting data from an excel file which include a column which shows duration as `mm:ss:ms`

[image]

But when I import the data to Power BI Desktop with Power Query, it converts this column to date/time format.

[image]

I don't know how can I solve this issue.

Any idea?

I already tried the code below:

```
format(((TableName[Duration] / 60)/60)/24, "HH:mm:ss")
```

and already tried to change the source column type from the excel to general.

Comment: Does the 2nd image you show (the table where the first value is 0.000823...) your desired result or what you're getting currently?

Comment: PowerBI doesn't support milliseconds in datetime.  You'll have to do a work-around and decide how to handle that information.  I like to just bring in the general format number from excel and multiply it by 86400 for total seconds in decimal format.  Here's some more on milliseconds in PowerBI here on stack overflow.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833631/how-to-deal-with-milliseconds-in-powerbi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerBI does not currently support milliseconds in date time datatype.  You can convert the excel doc to general, load it into PowerBI, and multiply the value by 86400 to get the total number of seconds.  Otherwise you'll need to bring it in as a string and do string manipulations to pull out the information you want.

[image]

Hope it helps.